# Behaviour of __subclasses__ when classes are deleted

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Edit: Generalised the question due to NPE's comment.

In a Python 2.7.3 interactive session:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> type("Bar", (Foo,), {})
<class '__main__.Bar'>
>>> Foo.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.Bar'>]
>>>
```

Also:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     pass
... 
>>> Foo.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.Bar'>]
>>> del Bar
>>> Foo.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.Bar'>]
```

How come `Bar` is still available via the `__subclasses__` function? I would have expected it to be garbage collected.

Conversely, if I want it to be garbage collected, how do I do it?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be specific to `type()`. I've tried `class Bar(Foo): pass` and then `del Bar`. I am seeing the same effect.

Comment: @NPE: Quite right, I have generalised the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/626283).  It would seem that what happens is the class's `__mro__` attribute stores a reference to itself, creating a reference cycle.  You can force a full gc run which will detect the cycle and delete the object:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
>>> import gc
>>> del Bar
>>> gc.collect()
3
>>> Foo.__subclasses__()
[]
```

Alternatively, if you enter other commands for a while, the gc will run on its own and collect the cycle.

Note that you have to be a bit careful when testing this interactively, because the interactive interpreter stores a reference to the most recently returned value in the "last value" variable `_`.  If you explicitly look at the subclass list and then immediately try to collect, it won't work, because the `_` variable will hold a list with a strong reference to the class.