# python - How to update __subclasses__ list after deleting an extending object

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

I should start by saying this might not be the best practice to go about so I'm open for suggestions. 
I'm relaying on the `__subclasses__` list of an object to run several operations. The issue is I wish to add and delete objects dynamically and I would like the `__subclasses__` list to reflect those changes. however I was not successful in updating it. 
Here's an example:

```
>>> class a(object):
>>>     pass
>>> class b(a):
>>>     pass
>>> del b
>>> a.__subclasses__()
[<class 'b'>]
```

I was expecting the get an empty list.
now since i'm using the a.`__subclasses__()` in my code I would like to have it updated whenever I delete an object.

I tried using garbage collector and call `collect()` right after removing the object like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422834/behaviour-of-subclasses-when-classes-are-deleted)  but that didn't help either.

if you think this is not the best practice and have a better way to go about it I'll be happy to hear :)

Comment: As you're open to suggestions, can you provide a bit of context of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Running `gc.collect()` does remove the subclass for me, as long as the subclass isn't reachable from `_`.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden i have a server api which enables a client to define a collection in mongo than generates CRUD for it. now after client is done it can request to dispose of that collection. i'm creating this collection with inheritance to a pre-define object to get a specific behaviour.  now i have different features which are enabled for all subclasses of my object. i relay in my implementation on that the subclasses list. is the context clearer now?

Comment: @user2357112 i'm using python 2.7.10

Comment: This is definitely still a duplicate. I can reproduce your issue under 2.7.10, because `_` references the list that `a.__subclasses__()` returns. Clearing `_` as I show in my answer clears the reference to the subclass and `gc.collect()` can reap it, at which point `a.__subclasses__()` returns an empty list. If you still see `b` listed, you have *more references somewhere* that still keep it alive.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses weak references to populate `__subclasses__()`. Simply run `gc.collect()` to clear it out.

If you still see `b` referenced in it, that just means *there are still more references to the object*. That could be as simple as the `_` last-result reference:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=14, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> class a(object): pass
...
>>> class b(a): pass
...
>>> del b
>>> a.__subclasses__()  # result will be referenced by _
[<class '__main__.b'>]
>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> a.__subclasses__()  # result will be referenced by _
[<class '__main__.b'>]
>>> 'Clear the _ reference by running a different expression'
'Clear the _ reference by running a different expression'
>>> gc.collect()
3
>>> a.__subclasses__()
[]
```

So once we made `_` point to a different object, no references to `b` are left and the subclasses weak reference is cleared too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm only using an interactive shell to run side tests. what you suggested does work in a small scenario with the clearing of the _. However in the context of my code and after calling the gc.collect() somehow i still have a reference to the deleted object in the subclasses list...

Comment: @DoronNadav: you have references **elsewhere** keeping the class alive. Those could be transitive references from other objects that have called `__subclasses__` and stored the result, or because there are further subclasses of the deleted class that keep it alive, etc. We can't tell you what code is holding those references however.

Comment: @DoronNadav: you may have to go search through the [`gc.get_referrers()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) pile to see what other things might referencing your class. You may have to recurse up until you find something that you recognise.